# Evaluating s(N) within a predicate's response, without losing functionality

Tags: list, prolog, clpfd, successor-arithmetics

I'm learning Prolog. I was experimenting with an `elemindex` predicate, with the form `elemindex(element, index, list)`, such that, for instance, `elemindex(1,0,[1,2,3,1]).` or `elemindex(3,0,[1,2,3,1]).`.

Due to instantiation restraints, I ended up with this:

```
elemindex(E, 0, [E|_]).
elemindex(E, s(M), [_|L]) :- elemindex(E,M,L).
```

However, if I query `?- elemindex(1,N,[1,2,3,1]).`, as in my example, Prolog responds:

```
N = 0
N = s(s(s(0)))
yes
```

This is certainly working, but I would like `s(s(s(0)))` to at least display as `3`. Furthermore, I cannot execute queries like `?- elemindex(E, 3, [1,2,3,4]).`, but changing the code to use `N is M+1` makes me lose the ability to evaluate the 1st kind of query.

So, my question is 2-fold:

1. How can I get `s(s(s(0)))` to display as `3` in my results?
2. How can I implement `elemindex` such that I can query for the element *and* the index?

Comment: Why are you using `s/1` in this context? Have you tried `N #= M + 1`? (use library `clpfd`)

Comment: @lurker could you explain what using `#=` would do? I'm very new to prolog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#=/2` is part of the CLPFD library, which is what you'd use to "reason" over integers. The `is/2` operator is designed to evaluate a completely known expression, so requires that the 2nd argument be completely bound so it's immediately evaluable. `#=/2` doesn't have that restriction. You won't get the instantiation error, and Prolog will attempt to solve for the variables. Do a google search on "Prolog clpfd".

Here's how it works with your code:

```
elemindex(E, 0, [E|_]).
elemindex(E, Index, [_|L]) :-
    Index #= N + 1,
    N #>= 0,
    elemindex(E, N, L).
```

Then queries:

```
| ?- elemindex(1,N,[1,2,3,1]).

N = 0 ? a

N = 3

no
| ?- elemindex(E, 3, [1,2,3,4]).

E = 4 ? a

no
| ?-
```

Comment: `elemindex(1, 1, L)` does not terminate - but it could